# Export a single entry of the registry

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, windows-registry

Is this posssible? For example i have a entry with the Name "DefaultProfile" and the Value "test". How can i export only this one entry not the full tree?

I was thinking about somethign like `reg export HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\DefaultProfile`

But this doesen't work.

I have managed to write a script to at least read the entry for further use. My code:

```
$query = reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\ /f DefaultProfile /s
[array]$rest = $query | select -first 3
$rest -split " " | Select -last 1
```

Comment: Have you tried [these suggestions](https://superuser.com/questions/595551/how-to-export-a-specific-registry-key-to-a-text-file-using-command-line)?

Comment: Why would it not work ? It definitely is possible to export one entry with one value.

Comment: Unfortunate this didin't work out for my need. (I mena the SetX thing)
@Overmind then how? At least not with the above showed command

Comment: So, if you have the values you need in a variable and that's what you need why don't you pipe it to a file?

Comment: When you say 'doesn't work', what error do you encounter or what exactly is happening ?

Comment: @Overmind, when I say, e.g., `reg export HKLM\Software\DefaultUserEnvironment\Path test2.reg` I get `ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.` The documentation seems clear enough: you have to specify the name of a key, not the name of a value.  The OP wants to export a single value.

Comment: I just tested and it worked fine. Note that if you have any spaces or strange characters, you have to put the whole HKEY thing with double quotes "HKEY\etc\".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Get-ItemProperty` to get the name and value of a Registry Key.

[Working with Registry Entries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-registry-entries?view=powershell-6)

[Get-ItemProperty](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty?view=powershell-6)

Sample Code:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellEngine | Select PowerShellVersion
```